# Need help defining a machine integer

Tags: why3

I'm using the [`mach.int` library](http://why3.lri.fr/stdlib-0.84/mach.int.html) in a specification (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377431/is-the-mach-int-library-a-default-part-of-why3)), and I'm trying to define a constant that is of type `int32`:

```
let constant_out1: int32 = 1 in
…
```

However, when analyzing this, why3 returns the message:

`This term has type int, but is expected to have type int32`

I noticed that `Bounded_int` (which `Int32` instantiates with type `int32`) has the following in it:

```
  val of_int (n:int) : t
    requires { "expl:integer overflow" in_bounds n }
    ensures  { to_int result = n }
```

However, I do not seem to be able to use this to cast `1` to `int32`. For example, if I use:

```
let constant_out1: int32 = Int32.of_int(1) in
…
```

I get the message `unbound symbol 'Int32.of_int'`. I've tried many permutations of this, all without any success. Can anyone provided guidance for how to tell why3 that I want `1` to be of type `int32`?